ReferenceError: nodeCrypto is not defined
I use NextJs to develop web3 app. But I have a problem when using @irys/sdk, I have trouble "ReferenceError: nodeCrypto is not defined"

I realize that it works without no errors when I run build and start, but environment dev it still has error

Error
ReferenceError: nodeCrypto is not defined
    at index.js:816:11
    at [project]/src/node_modules/@noble/ed25519/lib/esm/index.js [app-client] (ecmascript) (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_077437._.js:7577:3)


next.config.msj
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (!isServer) {
            config.resolve.alias = {
                ...config.resolve.alias,
                crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            };
        }
        return config;
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

It alert error from here (index)
const crypto = {
    node: nodeCrypto,
    web: typeof self === 'object' && 'crypto' in self ? self.crypto : undefined,
};

package.json
{
        "name": "next-app-template",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
                "dev": "next dev --turbo",
                "build": "next build",
                "start": "next start",
                "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx -c .eslintrc.json --fix"
        },
        "dependencies": {
                "@aptos-labs/ts-sdk": "1.22.2",
                "@aptos-labs/wallet-adapter-react": "^3.3.0",
                "@irys/sdk": "^0.2.10",
                "@nextui-org/accordion": "^2.0.38",
                "@nextui-org/button": "2.0.37",
                "@nextui-org/chip": "^2.0.32",
                "@nextui-org/code": "2.0.32",
                "@nextui-org/divider": "^2.0.31",
                "@nextui-org/dropdown": "^2.1.29",
                "@nextui-org/image": "^2.0.31",
                "@nextui-org/input": "2.2.4",
                "@nextui-org/kbd": "2.0.33",
                "@nextui-org/link": "2.0.34",
                "@nextui-org/listbox": "2.1.25",
                "@nextui-org/modal": "^2.0.39",
                "@nextui-org/navbar": "2.0.36",
                "@nextui-org/pagination": "^2.0.35",
                "@nextui-org/skeleton": "^2.0.31",
                "@nextui-org/snippet": "2.0.41",
                "@nextui-org/spinner": "^2.0.33",
                "@nextui-org/switch": "2.0.33",
                "@nextui-org/system": "2.2.5",
                "@nextui-org/table": "^2.0.39",
                "@nextui-org/tabs": "^2.0.35",
                "@nextui-org/theme": "2.2.9",
                "@nextui-org/tooltip": "^2.0.39",
                "@react-aria/ssr": "3.9.4",
                "@react-aria/visually-hidden": "3.8.12",
                "@splinetool/react-spline": "^4.0.0",
                "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.40.1",
                "axios": "^1.7.4",
                "clsx": "2.1.1",
                "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.3",
                "crypto": "^1.0.1",
                "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
                "framer-motion": "~11.1.1",
                "hugeicons-react": "^0.3.0",
                "intl-messageformat": "^10.5.0",
                "next": "14.2.4",
                "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
                "petra-plugin-wallet-adapter": "^0.4.4",
                "react": "18.3.1",
                "react-dom": "18.3.1",
                "react-hook-form": "^7.52.2",
                "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
                "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.1.0",
                "react-responsive": "^10.0.0",
                "react-simple-typewriter": "^5.0.1",
                "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
                "webpack": "^5.93.0"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
                "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
                "@types/node": "20.5.7",
                "@types/react": "18.3.3",
                "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
                "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.2.0",
                "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.2.0",
                "autoprefixer": "10.4.19",
                "eslint": "^8.57.0",
                "eslint-config-next": "14.2.1",
                "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
                "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
                "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
                "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
                "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
                "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
                "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
                "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.2.0",
                "postcss": "8.4.38",
                "tailwind-variants": "0.1.20",
                "tailwindcss": "3.4.3",
                "typescript": "5.0.4"
        }

How can I solve this problem, please help me :((

What is nodeCrypto referring to in that context?

Hi, at index, import * as nodeCrypto from 'crypto'

Is it a client component or server component? What version are you using of Node and Next?

I has just updated package.json

I try to use client comp, and try to add webpack for crypto but it still has error
